# Stick link to particular area on a background image

Tags: html, css

I am building a website where I want some area of the background image to have some dynamic text. So I created a DIV with following style:

```
html {
  background: url(pics/main-bg2_1280.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;     }
.thediv { height: 16%;
  width: 16%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 14%;
  left: 6%; }
```

but the div moves slightly when window resized
Is there any way to make sure that div is always in the same place regardless of window size and ratio (width x height)
Thanks

Comment: Try specifying margins in your property ``.thediv``

Comment: You need to measure where the div is to be positioned from the top and left side of the image, calculate that as  %s and then do the same math that the system has to do when you specify cover. Is using Javascript OK? (the problem being that the viewport can have absolutely any aspect ratio so this positioning needs actual calculation).